# Copy-pasting in gnome-terminal

Tags: copy-paste, gnome-terminal

Can I configure it to allow:

- select right-click to copy
- right-click or ctrl-v to paste?

Comment: Do you mean right click to copy and right click to paste?  Or right click to paste is preference #2 if right click to copy is not possible?

Answer (score 19):

You can make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> paste by changing the settings in the Edit->Keyboard Shortcuts menu.

But you might not want to do it, because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> is normally used by your shell as a way of typing characters literally.  For example, <kbd>Tab</kbd> normally makes the shell try to tab-complete a file name.  If you need to actually type a tab, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> lets you do that.

You can tell bash to use something else.  See [bash Commands for Changing Text](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-Text.html#Commands-For-Text) for some details.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> or <kbd>\</kbd> might work too.  Or it might just close your terminal.  :-)

I don't think the other things are possible.

As an alternative, you might like to try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd> for copy and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd> for paste.

By default, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd> pastes whatever you select with your mouse, even if you don't copy it.

I change it to do normal clipboard copy via Edit->Keyboard Shortcuts.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd> actually work in most appplications, but I don't think many people know about it.

Comment: I doubt I'll actually need to type a literal TAB, certainly not in the frequency in which I need to paste text.

Comment: `Shift`+`Del` is cut, too, but that doesn't apply to Gnome Terminal.

Comment: These shortcuts come from the [IBM CUA standards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Common_User_Access).

Comment: I'm not in front of a computer to check, but I'm pretty sure that if you make Ctrl+V paste and Ctrl+C copy, you can type Ctrl+Shift+V or C and it gets interpreted as Ctrl+V or Ctrl+C.

Answer (score 10):

The defaults in Gnome Terminal are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> for copy and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> for paste.  I don't think you can do right click Copy and Paste because Gnome Terminal uses right click to open the context menu.  And as Mikel said, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> is interpreted differently by the shell.

Answer (score 0):

mikel's got the best advice. Quite a few terminal emulators (of the *xvt variety, particularly) often don't have the luxury of the right-click menu for pasting, and some of them read from more than one configuration file (.Xdefaults, .xinitrc, etc) for the user's preferred "settings." As a result, folks have to use the keyboard a lot more often than they would in, say, GNOME Editor or jedit. So one gets used to using Shift-Insert for paste, and when they find out it doesn't work, and messes up the execution of a script in the process, it can be frustrating.

I'm happy to discover GNOME Terminal has configurable keyboard shortcuts now. I've been using one flavor or another of Ubuntu since 2009, but the last time I took any notice of it, this was something only Konsole had. You bet I made "Shift-Insert" ***my*** paste shortcut as soon as I read mikel's post to this thread.

BZT