# Share the clipboard between bash and X11

Tags: bash, x11, clipboard

In [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10721/copy-pasting-in-gnome-terminal) the top answer shows how to copy text that has been previously selected with the mouse on a gnome-terminal, to the clipboard in X11.

My question is: Say I copy a piece of text from the terminal using bash set-mark and copy keyboard shortcuts (i.e. `set-mark` + `M-w`). Is it possible to share this clipboard with X11?

**EDIT**: In the original question, I talked about sharing the clipboard with GNOME, but as Gilles points out below, GNOME doesn't specifically have a clipboard (it's general to X), so I have updated the question.

Comment: In gnome-terminal, you can also type Ctrl+Shift+C and Ctrl+Shift+V to copy and paste to the system clipboard.

Comment: See this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994563/integrate-readlines-kill-ring-and-the-x11-clipboard/28385543#28385543
But it is not working for me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bash's clipboard is internal to bash, bash doesn't connect to the X server.

What you could do is change the meaning of `M-w` to copy the selection to the X clipboard¹ in addition to bash's internal clipboard. However bash's integration is pretty loose, and I don't think there's a way to access the region information or the clipboard from bash code. You can make a key binding to copy the whole line to the X clipboard.²

```
if [[ -n $DISPLAY ]]; then
  copy_line_to_x_clipboard () {
    printf %s "$READLINE_LINE" | xsel -ib
  }
  bind -x '"\eW": copy_line_to_x_clipboard'
fi
```

If you want to do fancy things in the shell, switch to zsh, which (amongst other advantages) has far better integration between the line editor and the scripting language.

```
if [[ -n $DISPLAY ]]; then
  x-copy-region-as-kill () {
    zle copy-region-as-kill
    print -rn -- "$CUTBUFFER" | xsel -ib
  }
  x-kill-region () {
    zle kill-region
    print -rn -- "$CUTBUFFER" | xsel -ib
  }
  zle -N x-copy-region-as-kill
  zle -N x-kill-region
  bindkey '\C-w' x-kill-region
  bindkey '\ew' x-copy-region-as-kill
fi
```

¹ 
<sub>Gnome doesn't specifically have a clipboard, this is general to X.</sub>

² 
<sub>As of bash 4.1, there is a bug in the key parsing code: key sequences bound with `bind -x` may not be more than two characters long. I think bash 4.2 fixes some cases of longer prefixes but not all of them; I haven't researched the details.</sub>

Comment: Finally! Thanks a bunch! This `copy_line_to_x_clipboard` is exactly what I was missing for a very long time: the copy equivalent of shift+insert. I changed to ctrl-x (`bind -x '"\C-x"`) because `Esc` is too far to my taste (and C-c would be the dumbest possible choice).

Comment: Terminals normally have a meta key, which is bound to the alt key by default. Typing a character while holding it down is translated to `esc` followed by that character, so you can type it as `alt-w`.

Answer (score 9):

@Gilles already gave an excellent answer. I would just like to mention the existence of `xclip`, which is also a very useful way to copy terminal output to the X clipboard, by just piping anything into it:

```
$ cat /etc/passwd | xclip
```

Comment: Just a note that `xclip` copies into the primary buffer by default. To use the clipboard, use `xclip -selection clipboard`.