# Keyboard shortcut to copy current command from terminal to clipboard

Tags: bash, terminal, x11, keyboard-shortcuts, clipboard

Is there any way to copy current command (line typed in bash prompt) in terminal to X-clipboard without involving a mouse?

Comment: What is the “current command”? If you know what to copy, you can use xclip.

Comment: @Marco - Thank you - I expanded question. As for xclip, I am a newbie and do not know what it about. Could you explain?

Comment: @Gilles - Frankly, I do not really understand how the knowledge of how to put the selected text to the clipboard can help with putting the current command to the clipboard. Is there a keyboard shortcut, that allows to select the current command from bash prompt?

Comment: @Loom How does the `copy_line_to_x_clipboard` function in [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18701/how-to-share-the-clipboard-betwen-bash-and-x11/18704#18704) differ from what you're asking? If you're asking for a shortcut out of the box, then no, it doesn't exist, that's why I wrote a function. You can bind this function to whatever key you like (I also show how to do this in my answer).

Answer (score 7):

Yes, first you have to install xclip.
(`sudo apt-get install xclip`)

Then to  copy previous line:

```
echo !! | xclip
```

To Paste:
Middle click or

```
xclip -o
```

For example:

```
date
Wed Jul 24 15:46:54 IST 2013
echo !! | xclip

xclip -o
date
```

To copy **Output** of any command: `<command> | xclip`

However, this may fail if the command has special characters.

Comment: That fails if the command contains just about any special character.

Comment: Just add `:q` to `!!` of your command and it is fixed: `echo !!:q | xclip.` `:q` makes sure your variable is expanded and only then quoted. (Single quotes, so that nothing is interpreted by the shell.)