# Ctrl-y, yanking x-clipboard contents to terminal adds shell prompt string

Tags: clipboard, xbindkeys

Using [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18701/share-the-clipboard-between-bash-and-x11), i wrote custom function to yank text from x-clipboard to shell terminal on pressing `C-y`. I see two issues here,

```
copy_line_from_x_clipboard () {
    xsel -o
}

bind -x '"\C-y": copy_line_from_x_clipboard'
```

1) It adds shell prompt string, PS1 after pressing `C-y`. I prefer this function to behave exactly like `Ctrl - Shift -v`. Presently, it outputs,

```
CLIPBOARD_STUFF PS1$
```

2) It empties the system clipboard, after yanking the text first time. Second time, i press `C-y`, no more contents are getting yanked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update `$READLINE_LINE` and `$READLINE_POINT` in the function.  Insert `xsel -o` output at `$READLINE_POINT` of `$READLINE_LINE`.

```
copy_line_from_x_clipboard() {
        local n=$READLINE_POINT
        local l=$READLINE_LINE
        local s=$(xsel -o)
        READLINE_LINE=${l:0:$n}$s${l:$n:$((${#l}-n))}
        READLINE_POINT=$((n+${#s}))
}

bind -x '"\C-y": copy_line_from_x_clipboard'
```

Read [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) for details.

Comment: it works, yaegashi.... i understand `READLINE_LINE` changes are reflected in terminal... the new `READLINE_LINE` is a concatenated version of old contents plus yanked stuff. In the answer, i see a third string`${l:$n:$((${#l}-n))`. What does it do?

Comment: i donno, why `READLINE_LINE` is lengthy in the above answer but `READLINE_LINE=${l:0:$n}$s` does the work neatly as well.....

Comment: Don't you ever yank a text in the middle of command line by moving a cursor?

Comment: yes, i do... really didn't think of it.. thanks man..