# Select text without using mouse in Linux terminal

Tags: terminal, x11, keyboard-shortcuts

I know there is a shortcut to copy and paste contents in a Linux terminal. In addition, you can scroll through the contents of a terminal window by using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgDown</kbd>.

But is there any shortcut to select text or highlight text in a terminal without using a mouse? Unfortunately, I could not find an answer to this question; that is why I am asking here.

To clarify, I wanted to know about a keyboard command that will scroll through the terminal contents or output in the terminal. And it does not have to be a Gnome terminal; it should be some universal command for all kinds of the terminal. Like selecting the ID of a docker container after building the image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Share the clipboard between bash and X11](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18701/share-the-clipboard-between-bash-and-x11) To answer your question: it's **not** possible directly. As to whether the linked answer works in Wayland - I've no idea.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Share the clipboard between bash and X11](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18701/share-the-clipboard-between-bash-and-x11)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/).

The default shortcut to enter "copy mode" in tmux is `Ctrl-b [`, from where you use Vim-like shortcuts to select and yank text and to paste you use `Ctrl-b ]`.

Comment: I was looking for some command that will be universal for all terminal emulators, like Konsole, Gnome terminal and the list goes on.

Comment: tmux is independent of a terminal emulator. It is a [terminal multiplexer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_multiplexer).

Comment: indeed, and screen has a similar thing. and they're great, because if you accidentally close the window, you just open it back up like nothing happened

Answer (score 1):

Selecting text can be a function of your shell or of the of the terminal emulator you are using. [Alacritty](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty) is one that supports vi-like text selection with keyboard shortcuts.